# Finding Number of Occurrences Across Multiple Columns Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to find the number of occurrences of selected cells spread over 
multiple columns. How do I do that?

For example, I want to know how many times each of the following shows up.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `COUNTIF` function will give you your answer. Put this formula in column B, alongside each name:

```
=COUNTIF($P$2:$V$5,A1)
```

Where `$P$2:$V$5` is the range of cells you want to evaluate, and A1 is the cell with the name in it.